# Generalizing the pull-out property in conditional expectations

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathscr{G}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathscr{F}$. If $X$ and $Y$ are (integrable) random variables with $X$ being $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, the pull-out property $\mathbb{E}[XY \mid \mathscr{G}] = X \mathbb{E} [ Y \mid \mathscr{G} ]$ a.s. is well known. Written pointwise, the pull-out property reads as $\mathbb{E}[XY \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega) = X(\omega) \mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega)$ for almost all $\omega$.

Now assume that $X$ and $Y$ are random elements in some measurable spaces and $X$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable. It then follows that
$$\mathbb{E} [s(X)r(Y) \mid \mathscr{G} ](\omega) = s(X(\omega)) \mathbb{E} [ r(Y) \mid \mathscr{G} ](\omega) = \mathbb{E} [ s(X(\omega))r(Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega)$$
for almost all $\omega$ where $s$ and $r$ are measurable real-valued functions.

Question: Let $f(x,y)$ be jointly measurable in $x$ and $y$. Is it then true that

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega) = \mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega),Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega) $$
for almost all $\omega$?

The problem reduces to the question whether the indicator of a measurable set $B$ in the product space can be approximated by linear combinations of indicators over measurable sets of the form $B_1 \times B_2$ or equivalently, whether $f$ can be approximated by finite sums of products $s_k(x)r_k(y)$.

I doubt that this property holds when considering for example $B$ as the diagonal (for $X$ and $Y$ real-valued and not independent).

**EDIT:**

I think to have found some problems in the statement. The most important problem is that the statement $\mathbb{E} [ f(X,Y) \mid \mathcal{G} ](\omega) = \mathbb{E} [ f(X(\omega), Y) \mid \mathcal{G} ](\omega)$ does not make any sense, since in the expression $f(X(\omega), Y)$ the $\omega$ is not fixed and we can only take conditional expectations over random variables! So, if we consider instead $f(X(\omega_0), Y)$ for some fixed $\omega_0$ then the statement changes to $\mathbb{E} [ f(X,Y) \mid \mathcal{G} ](\omega) = \mathbb{E} [ f(X(\omega_0), Y) \mid \mathcal{G} ](\omega)$ for almost all $\omega$ such that $X(\omega) = X(\omega_0)$, i.e. a.s. on $X^{-1}(\{ X(\omega_0) \} )$. But now another problem appears, since $\{ X(\omega_0) \}$ is in general not contained in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{E}_X$.

Summing up together: The statement makes sense, if $\mathscr{E}_X$ is atomic. And in this case, the statement is true.
The statement does not make sense, if $\mathscr{E}_X$ is not atomic.

**EDIT 2:**

After some discussions in the comments, it is now clear where the problem is hidden. The expression $\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega),Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega)$ is to be interpreted as follows.
Firstly, for every $x$, define $Z_x(\omega) := \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega)$ as some fixed(!) chosen version for the conditional expectation of $f(x,Y)$ given $\mathscr{G}$. Note that such a version $Z_x(\omega)$ is chosen for every $x$. Secondly, define $\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega),Y) \mid \mathscr{G}](\omega) := Z_{X(\omega)}(\omega)$, i.e. by concatenation.

First of all, one has to check whether this map $\omega \mapsto Z(X(\omega),\omega)$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable in order to satisfy one of the constraints for the conditional expectation. Assume that it is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable. But then, in general it is NOT a conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid \mathscr{G}]$. The example with $f(x,y) = xy$, $X = Y \sim U(0,1)$ and $\mathscr{G} := \sigma(X)$ in the comments shows that if we choose as versions $Z_x(\omega) := x X(\omega) \mathbf{1}_{X(\omega) \neq x}$ (which depend on $x$!) then the desired equation between the conditional expectations does not hold.

So, this might be the reason, why I have not found this "rule" in mathematical literature on probability theory. However, note that
$\mathbb{E}[ f(X,Y) \mid \mathscr{G} ] = \mathbb{E}[ f(x,Y) \mid \mathscr{G}]$ a.s. on $\{ X = x \}$ (which is a direct consequence of the "local property" for conditional expectations). If $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(X)$ then this rule reads as
$\mathbb{E} [ f(X,Y) \mid X = x] = \mathbb{E} [ f(x,Y) \mid X = x ]$
and is often referred to as the "replacement rule". But, in order for this rule to be valid, it is necessary that the set $\{ X = x \}$ is measurable (which in general is not true, if $X$ takes values in a general measurable space $(E_X, \mathscr{E}_X)$.

Comment: For fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, set $$Z(x,\omega) := \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y) \mid \mathcal{G}](\omega)$$ (so it's a standard conditional expectation). Then $$\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega),Y) \mid \mathcal{G}](\omega) = Z(X(\omega),\omega).$$ So what am I missing? Why do you think that this is not well-defined?

Comment: The notation is the problem. Is $Z$ jointly measurable? In other words, is $\omega \mapsto Z(X(\omega), \omega)$ measurable? And note that $x \in E_X$ and $E_X$ is an arbitrary measurable space.

Comment: The problem lies in the negligible sets necessary to define conditional expectations. Consider $X=Y$ uniform on $(0,1)$, then $E(Y\mid X)=X$ almost surely and, for every $x$, $E(xY\mid X)=xX\mathbf 1_{X\ne x}$ almost surely since $P(X=x)=0$. Assume that these (legal) choices are made for $E(Y\mid X)$ and for $E(xY\mid X)$ for every $x$. Then $X(\omega)E(Y\mid X)(\omega)=X^2(\omega)$ and $E(X(\omega)Y\mid X)(\omega)=0$ for every $\omega$ hence, in this case, the suggested identity holds for no $\omega$ at all.

Comment: (P.S.: There should be a system on math.SE to signal non empty questions such as the present one.)

Comment: @Did: Thanks! Ok, so the problem is that although $Z(x,\omega)$ is some chosen version for the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y) \mid \mathscr{G}$ for each fixed $x$, the concatenation $Z(X(\omega),\omega)$ is not a conditional expectation for $\mathbb{E} [ f(X,Y) \mid \mathscr{G} ]$. I add some more information in a further EDIT above.

Comment: Related? http://i.stack.imgur.com/NhhlD.png

Comment: Yes, related with a special independence assumption.