# Conditional Expectations $E[h(X,Y)|X]$ and $E[h(x,Y)|X]$ agree at $X = x$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am having trouble understanding $E[\cdot |X = x]$. Now I know measure theory and the theory of conditional expectations decently well. So I understand that $E[h(X,Y) | X]$ is a random variable of the form $g(X)$ and it makes sense to call $g(x)$  $E[h(X,Y) | X = x]$.

Now I have a couple of questions regarding this. First, the function $g(x)$ is only determined on the range of $X$. So does this mean that anytime anyone writes $E[\cdot | X= x]$ they are implicitly requiring that $x$ is indeed a value achieved by $x$? Next, it is sometimes be the case that $[X=x]$ is a null set and since $E[\cdot | X]$ is only determined upto null sets itself, does that cause any issues?

Also, and this is my main question, people often freely replace $E[h(X,Y) | X=x]$ with $E[h(x,Y)|X=x]$. Can you give me a proof of why this is valid?

Comment: While you are waiting for a proper answer written by someone who understands the subject and can explain well, here are some leads for you. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be your probability space. First, we define _expectation conditioned on a sub-sigma-algebra_, $E[\cdot|\mathcal{H}]$, where $\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra. Next, we note that a r.v. $X:\Omega\to\Omega_X$ generates a sub-sigma-algebra $\sigma(X):=\{X^{-1}(E_{X}):E_{X}\in\Sigma_{X}\}$, where $(\Omega_X, \Sigma_{X})$ is a measurable space. Finally, we define $E[\cdot|X]:=E[\cdot|\sigma(X)]$.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. Since $E[\cdot | \sigma(X)]$ is a $\sigma(X)$ measurable, it has to be of the form $g(X)$ for some $X$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366543/generalizing-the-pull-out-property-in-conditional-expectations

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little better to think of $E(h(X, Y) \mid X = x)$ as the value of $E(h(X, Y) \mid X)$ on the set $\{X = x\}$. If $P(X = x) = 0$, then, since conditional expectations are only defined up to a.s. equivalence, the value assigned to $E(h(X, Y) \mid X = x)$ could be any real number, and can be modified at will. You would just be dealing with different a.s. equivalent versions of $E(h(X, Y) \mid X)$.

To prove that $E(h(X, Y) \mid X = x) = E(h(x, Y) \mid X = x)$, use
$$E(h(X, Y) \mid X)1_{\{X = x\}} = E(h(X, Y)1_{\{X = x\}} \mid X) = E(h(x, Y)1_{\{X = x\}} \mid X) = E(h(x, Y) \mid X)1_{\{X = x\}}$$
which means that $E(h(X, Y) \mid X) = E(h(x, Y) \mid X)$ a.s. on the set $\{X = x\}$.

Comment: I do not understand what will happen if $X\equiv Y$. Do we still assign the value of $E[h(X,Y)|X=x]$ at will? Could you please explain.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Nothing remarkable really happens if $X = Y$. It might be more accurate to say that the value $E(h(X, Y) \mid X = x)$ is not determined by the equivalence class of $E(h(X, Y) \mid X)$ in $L^1$. It's the same reason why if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g = f$ a.e., we can have $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

Comment: On a second look, this is a correct answer, which ought to be accepted or commented on by the OP. I was initially conflating the two parts of the question. In the first part, the value of $E(h(X,Y)|X=\cdot)$ can be changed at will in a $X_*P$-zero set in the co-domain of $X$. In the second part, $E(h(X,Y)|X=x)=E(h(x,Y)|X=x)$ holds for $X_*P$-a.e. $x$. For me, the most confusing part is what we formally mean by $E(h(x,Y)|X=x)$. I guess, we mean $g_x(x)$, where $g_x$ is a function s.t. $E(h(x,Y)|X)=g_x(X)$. So each member of a collection $\{g_x\}$ is evaluated at the corresponding $x$, right?

Comment: On the third look, your proof seems wrong. You have shown that at a single $x$ s.t. $P\{X=x\}=0$ we have wlog $E(h(X,Y)|X=x)=E(h(x,Y)|X=x)$, because the value of either can be changed at will, which can be extended to a countable set of $x$'s. However, it does not follow that  $E(h(X,Y)|X=x)=E(h(x,Y)|X=x)$ holds for $P_X$-a.e. $x$, which I believe is the goal. It is not even clear to me at this point why $E(h(x,Y)|X=x)$ would be a measurable function of $x$.

Answer (score -1):

$E( \cdot |X=x)$ is just a notation.For the last question, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent,$E[h(X,Y)|X]=(E[h(x,Y)])_{x=X}=g(X)$.So $E[h(X,Y)|X=x]=E[h(x,Y)]=g(x)$

Comment: People use it without independence as well, and it is why they use the notation $E[ \cdot | X = x]$ at all.